# Проблемы с Visual Studio Code. "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again."

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Установил vs code, но случилась такая проблема, что когда я изменяю настройки, вылезает это и не дает мне ничего поменять:
[image: Скриншот]

Нажимаю справа внизу и перехожу в настройки. Открывает json файл:
[image: Скриншот2]

Показывает ошибку в коде, дальше не знаю как решить проблему.

Comment: вы запятую пропустили после `runInTermenal: true`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я просто начинающий программист (как вы уже поняли) и не знаю json